# Using sidebar.php within a Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

I have recently installed Woocommerce on a self-built theme and got an error message telling me that I needed to add a sidebar.php code to my theme. The error message was followed by a list of widgets in a messy, un-styled list. The widgets included a search bar, a list of pages in my site and an archives and categories list. I have now created sidebar.php by following a tutorial which seems to have worked – I have included the code I used below.

What I'm finding unusual is that since adding the sidebar, these widgets seem to have disappeared and I now have to add them manually using the widgets tab under the appearance menu. I can't figure out why they might have disappeared?

I always assumed that when adding a sidebar, I'd have to add the widgets via PHP code – otherwise wouldn't the sidebar clash with other templates? For example, I can add the Woocommerce widgets for my shop pages, but when I want to create blog posts I'll need different widgets, and the Woocommerce ones will still be in the sidebar and vice-versa.

Maybe I've gone about doing this the wrong way.. perhaps somebody can point me in the right direction? I've been googling this and have watched some youtube tutorials but haven't found the answers I'm looking for.

My code is as follows:

**functions.php**

```
function enable_widgets() {

    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name' => 'Main Sidebar',
            'id'   => 'sidebar',
            'description'   => 'Here you can add widgets to the main sidebar.',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>',
            'before_title'  => '<h5 id="widget-heading">',
            'after_title'   => '</h5>'
    ));

 }

 add_action('widgets_init','enable_widgets');
```

**sidebar.php**

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: The '}' is missing at the end of the function.

Comment: Thanks, well spotted. I'll update that now, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue as it's there in the functions.php of my theme, I must have just missed it when copying it across.

Comment: Most of the theme register different sidebars for different templates. For example, a sidebar named 'Product Sidebar' for Shop page and another sidebar named 'Blog Sidebar' for Blog page. So it would not be clash.

Comment: Ah right - so if the Woocommerce template calls for the sidebar like this: 
`<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
   ?>`
How could I get it to call the sidebar if it was called `shop-sidebar.php`?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Show Woocommerce sidebar on your custom made template?

Comment: Yes, so if I already have `sidebar.php`, I was thinking I could make another sidebar and call it something like `shop-sidebar.php` – then I'd need to get the main woocommerce template (`archive-product.php`) to hook this new sidebar in. The PHP hook I pasted above is from the `archive-product.php` template. What I'm wondering is whether I can adapt the hook to tell it to get the shop-sidebar, or to I need to replace the hook entirely with something like: `get_sidebar( 'shop-sidebar.php' )`? I hope I'm not too far off the mark here – my PHP skills are very basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In woocommerce/templates/global/sidebar.php, you can see how woocommerce displays the sidebar.

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_sidebar( 'shop' ); ?>
```

It will search for sidebar-shop.php first, and then sidebar.php.
So all you need to do is create sidebar-shop.php under your theme folder.

And in your sidebar-shop.php, display the widget area you have registered.

**sidebar-shop.php**

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar'); ?>
</div>
```

There is another approach to show woocommerce specific widget area using the same sidebar.php. Since WooCommerce has some [conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/), we could use *is_woocommerce*() to determine the page uses WooCommerce templates or not.

**sidebar.php**

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <?php

    if ( is_woocommerce() ) {
       dynamic_sidebar('sidebar');
    } else {
       dynamic_sidebar('default-sidebar');
    }

   ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, just what I was looking for. Thank you